# Object breaks while using armature

Tags: armature

Ok so first of I am new to blender but have the very basics figured out. I have a yoga mat that I am trying to have follow a bone structure but when bending the object it breaks apart - I would like to have the pieces remain together. - Object is parented to the armature using "parent with automatic weights." The object is one single piece with the armature bones perfectly positioned where I want the mat to fold.

*Note I don't want the mat to "roll up" rather the sections "fold" with the bones as that is the design of the mat.

[image: mat image]
enter image description here

Comment: is the real object made of one piece? If so, why did you separate it into several meshes?

Comment: It is one piece, after the armature is applied it starts to separate the mesh. The object mesh first started out as individual pieces that I duplicated and in edit mode then rejoined each section using connect vertex pairs... I feel like its a bone weight issue or something relatively simple that I overlooked. I kept everything super precise to make sure nothing was broken

Comment: it can't be one mesh, otherwise the parts wouldn't separate, if you've duplicated the parts, you need afterwards to merge the vertices by distance so that the vertices join and the object is only made of one mesh and not several

Comment: Ok cool. I will look into your suggestions. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: if you need any help please add some informations in your initial question, perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/